# how to validate if an array is empty using validator

Tags: node.js, api

I need to check if the users have filled in array values or they are empty .
I went through the [validator docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)

but I don't see any function which works on array .

isEmpty(str)    check if the string has a length of zero.

Comment: Just to be sure: `['', '']` is an empty array for you? or just `[]` which is for the rest of us.

Comment: there should atleast one character in array ['a'] works fine but [' '] doesn't

Comment: `' '` is not empty for me, `''` is. So please edit your question with exactly what do you consider ir to be empty. Unless you want half answers.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

[validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) validates and sanitizes strings only. so none of the methods in there will help you achieve what you want. just use [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property.

Answer (score 0):

If by empty array, you mean: `[]`

This will do:

```
if(!array.length)
  console.log(`I'm not empty`);
```

If you mean an array with empty values, such as: `[null, '']`

You can use: **[.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** to check if at least one item is empty, or **[.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)** to check that every item is empty.

```
const array = [null, ''];

!array.some(Boolean); // True if at least one is falsy
!array.every(Boolean); // True if every item is falsy
```

If you want some custom validation, you can pass your custom function too.

```
function empty(item) {
   // What ever you consider by empty, check it here
   // return true if it is empty
   if(typeof item === 'string')
      return !item.trim();

   return !item;
}

array.some(empty); // true if at least one is empty
array.every(empty); // true if all of them are empty
```